# How would I implement a vertical version of this horizontal dynamic header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

On The Economist website, there is a horizontal header that only appears after you scroll down the page once. See here:

http://www.economist.com/blogs/asiaview/2010/12/china_and_nobel_peace_prize

What I want is a vertical version of this that would come out of the left or right side of the page and expand over the page content that is already in place.

Anyone know of an existing plugin or how I could build something like that in jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple jQuery plugin that should work for you:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.scrollToast = function(options) {
        var settings = options || {};
        var offset = settings.offset;
        var toast = settings.toast;
        var $toast = $(toast);
        var hidden = true;

        // prepare the toast:
        $toast.css({
            display: 'none',
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '0px',
            left: '0px',
            zIindex: '1',
            overflow: 'hidden'
        });


        this.bind("scroll", function($event) {
            var top = $(this).scrollTop();
            if ((top >= offset && hidden) || (top < offset && !hidden)) {
                hidden = !hidden;
                $toast.animate(
                    {width: "toggle"});               
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

**Usage**: `$(window).scrollToast({toast: "#toast", offset: 50});`, where `#toast` is a selector indicating the element to slide out, and `offset` is how long you want the user to scroll before the toast appears.

**Notes**:

- Uses CSS `position:fixed` and an elevated `z-index` to make the toast element appear on top of other content.
- When the target element is scrolled to a value equal to or beyond `offset`, the toast element is slid out (it is initially hidden).
- When the target element is scrolled to a value less than `offset` the toast element is slid back in.
- Could easily be extended to show the toast on the other edge of the screen or the top or bottom.
- Will probably work on any scrollable element, but I've used `$(window)` because it seems to fit the use case you described.

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/56dTA/

Comment: That's awesome, dude! Edit: Damn, don't have enough juice to vote you up - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's pretty easy to build:

You create a:

```
<div id="hiddenmenu">
This Appears on scrolldown
</div>
```

This div should be absolute positionend, and display:none;

With the jQuery, on scroll-down you use `$('#hiddenmenu').show();`
That's pretty much it, if you need the full code, just ask and I'll post it.